# Let $f$ be uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, where $a<b$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)$ exist.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from $(a,b)$, $a<b$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$$ exist.

My attempt so far:

It is clear that $a \in E'$. Therefore, we can define a limit at this point, if it exists. The limit as $x \to a$ of $f(x)$ exists iff (by definition): Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),q)<\epsilon$ for all $x \in E$ with $d_X(x,a) < \delta$, where $q$ is the limit of $f$ at $a$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we know that given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all points in $E$ contained in balls of radius $\delta$, the mapping of the balls into $\mathbb{R}$ is entirely contained in a ball of radius $\epsilon$.

Can someone point me in the right direction or to any fact I may use? Thanks.

Comment: How does $X$, $Y$ relate to the question in the title? Could you please clarify?

Comment: What are $E$ and $E'$?

Answer (score 2):

You don't know what the limit of $f(x)$ from the right at $a$ might be. The Cauchy criterion comes to the rescue: Let $x_n\to a.$  Use uniform continuity to show $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy.